# Input parameter webservice method

Tags: c#, exception, parameters

I have a class that is called MyMethodQuery that contains a property and a builder who is to check that the property is correctly filled in:

```
public class MyMethodQuery
   {
       public string Id { get; set; }

       public MyMethodQuery ()
       {
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Id))
               throw new System.ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be null");
       }
   }
```

My method:

```
public string MyMethod(MyMethodQuery MyMethodQuery)
{
   return "it's ok !";
}
```

When I call my method with an id I filled a thrown exception :

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred 
Additional information: Parameter can not be null
```

I do not understand

Thank you

Comment: You need to initialized your Id property.

Comment: I do not how see making, this variable is informed to the appeal of the method directly (via the utility SoapUI for example)

Answer (score 1):

That's should be expected. When you create a new instance of MyMethodQuery the constructor of that class is called and at that point the ID field is still null

You could change your constructor to receive an initial value

```
public class MyMethodQuery
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public MyMethodQuery(string initialValue = "1")
    {
        this.Id = initialValue;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Id))
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be null");
    }
}
```

Of course it will be beneficial to understand your code if you call your variables with a different name than the class name

```
void Main()
{
    MyMethodQuery anInstance = new MyMethodQuery("1");   
}
```

Comment: This variable is informed to the appeal of the method directly (via the utility SoapUI for example)

Comment: I do not understand why the property is null while I soap the information in the envelope soap

Comment: A call to _MyMethodQuery()_ (the constructor of the class)  is executed to create the instance in which the Id property will be set. Without the c# 6.0 syntax for auto-properties any instance variable (Id in your case) is still not initialized

Comment: `public string Id{ get; set; } = "ini";`
If I don't inform the property then she will be equal 'ini'. I don't want this behavior

Comment: Yes, you could write in that way if you use C# 6.0, however the effect is the same if you have a parameter in your constructor and use it to initialize the Id field

Comment: The property would always have a value. I don't want this behavior

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c#6 you can initialize the auto-property directly

```
public class MyMethodQuery
 {
    public string Id { get; set; } = "Inialized";

   public MyMethodQuery ()
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Id))
           throw new System.ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be null");
   }
```

}